# R programming /get number of variables in a column -

Tags: r, list, subset

I am currently taking the Getting and Cleaning Data Course on Coursera :D

The first quiz contained this question: How many properties are worth more than 1000 000$? Looking at the code book it is clear, properties are listed in column VAL and assigned the number 24 for houses worth equal or more than 1 mio dollar.

My first attempt to solve this question looked like this:

```
length(data$VAL[data$VAL=="24"])
```

however this didnt get me the right answer.
By chance (and after some nervous breakdowns) i tried this (and it worked):

```
length(data$VAL[!is.na(data$VAL) & data$VAL=="24"])
```

Now i had the right solution but i dont really understand why this works. In my first attempt above it seems all the NAs were included too, although i specified for `data$VAL=="24"`

Can anybody please elaborate as to why my first guess didnt work bit the second did? It seems counterintuitive to me. :/

Best wishes and thanks for your thoughts, 
Dominic

Comment: NAs have some confusing behavior, see [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/07/understanding-na-in-r.html) and [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#missing-values-3). And you are experiencing some of that. An alternative strategy would be `sum(dat$VAL == 24, na.rm = TRUE)` and that dodges that NA index weirdness.

Comment: Cool! Many thx, Nate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
data = data.frame(VAL=c('24','24','24',NA,NA))
```

Let's first look at

```
data$VAL=="24"
```

which returns

```
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
```

So when you do

```
data$VAL[data$VAL=="24"]
```

We tell R to include from `data$VAL` all elements where `data$VAL=="24"` is `TRUE`, and to leave out those where it is `FALSE` (try for example `c(1,2,3)[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)]`). For the fourth and fifth element, you specify not `TRUE` or `FALSE` to include the element, but `NA` and `NA`. So you get

```
[1] 24   24   24   <NA> <NA>
```

which has indeed a length of `5`. When you do

```
data$VAL[!is.na(data$VAL) & data$VAL=="24"]
```

you specify that you do not want to take the elements that are `NA`, and thus the length is `3`.

If we take one step back, we see that we want to count the number of `TRUE`'s in `data$VAL=="24"`. We can also do that with for example:

```
sum(data$VAL=="24",na.rm=TRUE)
```

which returns `3`, since the `na.rm` argument specifies that we want to remove the `NA`'s from the vector before summing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! This is my first question on stackoverflow. I did not expect such detailed replies! Many thanks for your time and expertise! :-D coming from a total humanities background, expect to see more questions coming from me in retrospect i should have gone with na.rm= TRUE. Somehow i thought of this at first but for some reason i did not pursue that thought. Again, many thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

The vector `data$VAL == "24"` has values which are either `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NA`, depending on whether `data$VAL` is 24, something else but not `NA`, or `NA`. When you subset a vector using a logical vector, `NA`s are included but the values become `NA` themselves:

```
> a <- 1:5
> a[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NA)]
[1]  1  3 NA
```

A shortcut for your case would have been `sum(data$VAL==24, na.rm = TRUE)` which sums the logical vector, converting it into 0s and 1s, and removing `NA`s.